# ¿Cómo hacer un post y un get de un web service con un nested object no relacional?

Tags: mongoose

Esta es mi entidad Cliente:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const clienteSchema = new Schema({
  nombre: String,
  email: String,
  cuil: String,
  telefono: Number,
  direccion: {
    calle: String,
    numero: Number,
    piso: String,
    departamento: Number
  }
});

mongoose.model('clientes', clienteSchema);
```

Y estos son mis métodos de los web services: `post` y `get` del controlador Clientes:

```js
app.get('/api/clientes', async (req, res) => {
  console.info('Obteniendo clientes');
  Cliente = await Cliente.find()
    .populate(cliente, {path: "direcciones"}, function(err,clientes) {
      res.send(clientes);
    });
  });

app.post('/api/clientes', async (req, res) => {
  const {nombre, email, cuil, telefono, direccion} = req.body;
  const cliente = new Cliente({
    nombre,
    email,
    cuil,
    telefono,
    direccion: new Direccion({
      calle: {type: String},
      numero:{type: Number},
      piso:{type: String},
      departamento:{type: Number}
      }),
    type:Object 
  });

  try {
    let nuevoCliente = await cliente.save(); 
    res.status(201).send(nuevoCliente); 
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'MongoError') {
      res.status(409).send(err.message);
    }
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre, si yo quiero, por ejemplo:

```js
{
  "nombre":"javier savietto",
  "email": "j.savietto@yahoo.com",
  "cuil": "3819392310321",
  "telefono": 8391932,
  "direccion": {
    "calle": "manhattan 38239",
    "numero": 56,
    "piso": "PB",
    "departamento": 4
  }
}
```

En vez de:

```js
{
  "nombre": "javier savietto",
  "email": "j.savietto@yahoo.com",
  "cuil": "3819392310321",
  "telefono": 8391932,
  "direccion": { "9319329jiadsnjdaj2" }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, cuando se trabaja con bases de datos no relacionales, no hablamos de relaciones ni entidades. Hablamos en todo caso de modelos y referencias.

Veo que usas [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) para definir los esquemas de documentos para tu base de datos. Podrías crear referencias entre dichos modelos al definir tus esquemas.

También por tu código veo que haces lo siguiente:

```js
...
direccion: new Direccion({ ... }),
...
```

dándome a entender que tienes un modelo llamado Dirección.

---

## Solución: REFERENCIA A UN DOCUMENTO ÚNICO

Mongoose te ofrece una manera cómoda de hacer una referencia de un documento en una colección a otro documento en otra colección. (Siempre en la misma base de datos).

En este caso tienes dos modelos: `Cliente` y `Dirección`, y vas a crear una referencia dentro de un documento de la colección de clientes a un documento de la colección de direcciones.

**Modelo `Cliente`**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const clienteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: String,
  email: String,
  cuil: String,
  telefono: Number,
  direccion: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectID,
    ref: 'Direccion'
  }
}, {
  collection: 'clientes'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cliente', clienteSchema);
```

**Modelo `Direccion`**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const direccionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  calle: String,
  numero: Number,
  piso: String,
  departamento: Number
}, {
  collection: 'direcciones'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Direccion', direccionSchema);
```

En nuestro modelo `Cliente` (en singular) hemos definido un campo llamado `dirección`, el cuál es una referencia a un documento de tipo `Direccion`.

Algo importante a observar, es que en la medida de lo posible tratemos de ser coherentes con los nombres de los objetos con los cuales estamos trabajando.

Puedes notar que al método `Schema()` le he pasado 2 objetos:

1. La definición de los campos del esquema.
2. El nombre de la colección.

De esta forma controlamos el comportamiento por defecto de Mongoose que *pluraliza* los nombres de las colecciones a partir del nombre del modelo.

Si dejamos que Mongoose haga esto, podríamos terminar con nombres de colecciones poco amigables en castellano. Es por eso que es mejor definir explícitamente el nombre de la colección usando el atributo `collection` cuyo valor será el nombre de la colección que deseamos.

Puedes leer más sobre esta y otras opciones en la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).

Un modelo es una Clase a partir de la cual podemos crear objetos. Es por ello que ponemos el nombre del modelo con la primera letra mayúscula y en singular.

Cuando trabajamos con MongoDB, por lo general los nombres de las colecciones se colocan en plural (como ya hemos visto), de esta forma la colección `clientes` contendrá documentos del tipo `Cliente`, y la colección `direcciones` contendrá documentos del tipo `Dirección`.

Así tendremos algo de orden al momento de trabajar con nuestros objetos.

Para obtener el resultado que esperas, usando este tipo de referencia en Mongoose, debes usar el método [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) en tu consulta:

```js
// método get()

app.get('/api/clientes', (req, res) => { // <- no necesitas una función async si usas callback en el método find()
  console.info('Obteniendo clientes');
  Cliente
    .find()
     //El campo que deseo 'poblar', seguido de los campos que deseo mostrar
    .populate('direccion', 'calle piso numero departamento')
    .exec((err, clientes) => {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
      }
      return res.status(200).json(clientes);
    });
});


// método post()

app.post('/api/clientes', async (req, res) => {
  // Debemos primero salvar los datos de la dirección antes de poder salvar los datos 
  // del cliente, ya que para salvar los mismos necesitamos el valor de ObjectId
  // de la dirección al ser salvada en la bd.
  // Hay otras formas de hacerlo sin necesidad de hacer la doble consulta a la base de datos,
  // pero por ahora lo mostraré así para mantenerlo simple.
  try {
    const direccion = new Direccion(req.body.direccion);
    direccion = await direccion.save();
    // direccion es el objeto ya guardado en DB y tiene un campo _id asignado

    const cliente = new Cliente({
      nombre = req.body.nombre,
      email = req.body.email,
      cuil = req.body.cuil,
      telefono = req.body.telefono,
      direccion = direccion._id // <- Aqui pasamos el ID del elemento ya guardado
    });

    const nuevoCliente = await cliente.save();
    return res.status(201.json(nuevoCliente);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'MongoError') {
      return res.status(409).json({error: err.message});
    }
    return res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
  }
});
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma de crear una referencia de un documento de la colección clientes a un documento de la colección direcciones.

Si no usas el método `populate()` de Mongoose, cuando ejecutes la consulta, el resultado será un documento (o documentos) de clientes cuyo campo dirección sólo tendrá el valor del campo `_id` perteneciente a un documento de la colección de direcciones.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas al respecto.